# To what extend can I 'ban' javascript? given that none js functionality is very complex

Tags: javascript

I am developing a website utilizing PHP, MYSQL and jquery.

In one particular form, you have a select box to choose your ticket type.

Depending on your ticket type you then get 4 extra options.

These options are displayed using jquery, and show/hide a div.
If you change your option back, then the values of the extra options are set to 'NO', and the division hidden.

The problem occurs when a user does not have javascript on. If they have javascript disabled, the four extra options are always displayed meaning the user can set these options without being required to even select a ticket, or more likely when selecting an incompatible ticket.

The functionality relies on javascript, and adding none-javascript functionality is excessively complex.

I know there is a large debate about whether sites should have none-javascript versions. Could someone perhaps state their thoughts on this particular situation?

Thanks

Comment: If your site is absolutely not useable without JavaScript, then let the user know.

Comment: I tend to use the same approach here than with IE6 : Ensure that the website can be used, but don't bother if it look like a complete mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design your UI in such a way that, even if the user has Javascript disabled and all options are visible, it is clear to the user what to do.

Next, once the user submits the form, do a server-side check on the submitted data. For example, if the first select box has no value, return to the form and display an error message accordingly. Or if the first select box did have a valid value, pick the correct second select box to check.

Note that you would have to do the server-side validation anyway, so in theory, this should be no extra work.

Comment: I am using CodeIgniter and its form validation class, as such validating that if no ticket is selected, the extra options are not selected either is a little extra hassle.

At this point, my code is getting more and more complex to try and cater for none js users.

I do however suppose that i should be verifying the above, even if javascript is enabled..

In terms of UI are you suggesting i should put within some noscript tags, extra information stating 'if you do not select a ticket do not select these either'?

Such that if a user does not have js, it may not look good, but it is explained?

Comment: @ThomasClowes Using a noscript tag to add additional instruction for non-JS users may indeed be a good idea. How exactly you present the information is largely dependant on the rest of your layout. UI is hard to get right, however, so depending on how many of your users do not have JS enabled, it may not be worth the time for you.

Answer (score 1):

The Cardinal Rule: people with javascript disabled are very used to every other site not working (heck, these people aren't even on Facebook).

If for some reason a large portion of your market might have javascript disabled (means they know what they're doing even to disable it, so likely older, security-conscious, tech-savvy individuals), put a `<noscript></noscript>` warning in a visible place (either on that form only, or somewhere earlier on in the visit) and call it good.

If you have a mobile market, that might be another story...

Comment: What, facebook does not run without Javascript? That's so silly, it's not like it couldn't (at least to a basic extent).

Comment: It displays the feed and stuff, but no commenting, liking, chatting, etc. from what I can tell. It's at the "why bother" state...

Comment: So basically tell the none js user what they have to do, which had they had js they wouldnt have to worry about?

Most modern mobiles run javascript now??

Comment: Yes, most modern browsers (mobile or desktop) run javascript, and have it enabled by default.  Program for the 99%.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure this is a duplicate, but to answer your question:

- You should not depend on javascript execution for avoiding the user from doing something wrong with the server. That means that you should track if the user has some "ticket" thing in the server before letting him do something.
- You should display the divs using Javascript. This is as easy as initially having them hidden by CSS and then showing them with something along the lines of `$('.myDivs').css('visibility', 'visible');`. This way users without JS won't even see the divs.
- `<noscript>` tags and their contents only show without javascript turned on.
- You should warn the user before he begins using the system that Javascript is necessary (maybe in a `<noscript>` tag?).

Comment: Fair point about not depending on javascript to avoid things being done wrong.

I can see the benefit of verifying everything server side as well (at least), but what about the fact that it almost not worth the overcomplication of my code to try and develop for non javascript users?

Comment: @ThomasClowes If I were you, I'd just make it javascript-only until people start to complain. But do make sure it works at least on major browsers, as asking the user to run on the latest version is not as friendly as asking them to turn on javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should show all the divs by default. Hide them using Javascript when the page loads. Inside the divs, have `<noscript>` tags with a description when the extra options in the `div` are applicable. Don't reset the extra options to "No" using Javascript, do this logic on the server. (Besides, it's annoying in case the user picks a ticket type, fills the options out, changes the ticket type – maybe because of a misclick – then changes it back and has to do it all over again.)

By now it's also probably safe to assume your user has Javascript *available*, but chooses not to enable it by default. You could get away with just disclosing the requirement, and telling the user to enable JS for your site.

Comment: I see your point with checking server side BUT doing that gets a little complex, when a javascript requirement avoids it.

In terms of 'doing it all over again' - it is only a few select boxes - not that much stress, but again I see your point.

Comment: @Thomas Why would it be complex? It's the same bunch of variables, and the logic is the same as well. Also, it's probably good practice to check submitted data on the server anyway – as a rule you shouldn't trust any external input to be sensible.